# After Importing android project

Tags: android

I developed a project in android [API 13] but when i tried to run that project in other system having android[API 8] . 
It says

**Unable to resolve target 'android-13'**

How to resolve this bug???

Comment: change the project build target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target is specified in the AndroidManifest. You can change it there, but still if you use some API-13 functions the code might fail to compile when you change that.

**EDIT**: the property is called `minSdkVersion`

Comment: But we have to update at 2 places
 1) project.properties   2) AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The other "system", which I assume is a development machine doesn't have API level 13 installed. You can do so using the SDK manager.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html

Comment: Test in android phone/emulator? You should then deploy the pre-built APK with minSdkVersion = 8 instead of building the code. I dont think I still get what you are trying to do :).

Answer (score 0):

Open the project.properties file and edit the min sdk version.